# How to check if mouse scroll top or bottom direction?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get mouse direction function. I would like to know how to check if mouse scroll top or bottom direction.

Every time check that if body scroll top or bottom direction:

```
if(scroll top... ) {
    do something.....
}

if(scroll bottom... ) {
    do something.....
}
```

CSS:

```
body { 
    height:1400px; 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    position:relative; 
}
.get-direction-info-here {
    width:150px; 
    height:30px; 
    background:red; 
    display:block; 
    font-size:14px; 
    line-height:30px; 
    color:#fff; 
    position:fixed; 
    top:0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="get-direction-info-here">
    Scroll direction: <!-- Scroll TOP --> / <!--Scroll Bottom-->
</div>

<div class="direction-info"> </div>
```

Comment: Scroll position and mouse position are different.  Which do you want?

Comment: Where is the code that you wrote and trying to use to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [mouse wheel events](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-mouse-wheel/) in HTML5 to detect mouse wheel action. Up / down is determined by whether the delta is positive (scolling up) or negative (scrolling down).

```js
     window.onload = function() {

     var directionInfo = document.getElementById("directionInfo");
     
     if (directionInfo.addEventListener) {
      directionInfo.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler, false);
      directionInfo.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", MouseWheelHandler, false);
     }
     else directionInfo.attachEvent("onmousewheel", MouseWheelHandler);
     
     function MouseWheelHandler(e) {
    
      // cross-browser wheel delta
      var e = window.event || e;
      var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
      if(delta > 0)
              directionInfo.innerText = 'Up';
            else
              directionInfo.innerText = 'Down';
      return false;
     }
    
    }
```

```css
.direction-info {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid green;
  }
```

```html
<div id="directionInfo" class="direction-info"> </div>
```

Comment: @jitujahagirdar, good. Are you going to mark it as the answer?

Comment: Ya its really help for me. Thank you ..( :

Answer (score 0):

```js
     window.onload = function() {

     var directionInfo = document.getElementById("directionInfo");
     
     if (directionInfo.addEventListener) {
      directionInfo.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler, false);
      directionInfo.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", MouseWheelHandler, false);
     }
     else directionInfo.attachEvent("onmousewheel", MouseWheelHandler);
     
     function MouseWheelHandler(e) {
    
      // cross-browser wheel delta
      var e = window.event || e;
      var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
      if(delta > 0)
              directionInfo.innerText = 'Up';
            else
              directionInfo.innerText = 'Down';
      return false;
     }
    
    }
```

```css
.direction-info {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid green;
  }
```

```html
<div id="directionInfo" class="direction-info"> </div>
```